# Scaled path saved to pdf renders as if stroke width was scaled in everything except inkscape

Tags: pdf, inkscape

Hopefully this is me doing something wrong, but if my suspicions are a correct and it's a bug I'll submit a bug report.

I have an svg file (originally drawn by matplotlib, but I suspect that's not relevant). I scaled some paths in height only (and clipped them), now when I load the pdf in evince, gimp or gv *-- but not inkscape -- the stroke width is scaled in height as well, though I did not have the *scale stroke when scaling* affect selected.

Opening the pdf in inkscape and exporting as .png:

[image]

opening the same pdf in the Gimp:

[image]

some unscaled paths are seen on the left as well.

Is there anything I can do about this?  I really need to work on the svg rather than going back to the data processing and modifying the code in matplotlib, and I need to scale by an integer by typing, not by dragging.

*Edit:* **I've just install foxit on my windows vm - the same as everything except inkscape*

*Edit2: Here's a minimal(ish) svg that shows the problem (really, no SVG upload?):*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="86.874992"
   height="33.008114"
   viewBox="0 0 69.499992 26.406493"
   id="svg2">
  <metadata
     id="metadata1778">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs4"
     style="stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round">
    <style
       type="text/css"
       id="style6" />
  </defs>
  <path
     d="m 73.4966,215.574 2.6784,0.104 5.9148,0.341 11.9412,-0.054 21.874,-0.079 9.597,-0.184 4.911,-0.321 2.901,-0.402 4.018,-0.785 0.446,-0.378 0.447,-0.689 0.446,-1.086 0.558,-2.019 0.67,-3.471 0.781,-5.406 1.227,-10.454"
     transform="translate(-72.968769,-190.125)"
     clip-path="url(#p19969a3f5c)"
     id="path722"
     style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:#0000ff;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round" />
  <defs
     id="defs1765">
    <clipPath
       id="p19969a3f5c">
      <rect
         width="446.39999"
         height="101.64706"
         x="72"
         y="165.17647"
         id="rect1774"
         style="stroke-linecap:square;stroke-linejoin:round" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

*To demonstrate, stretch in height only than save as pdf and open in your viewer of choice (except inkscape).

Note that I've added a fill to prove that it's just a path and not an object being scaled

More new info - if I remove the clip, it scales as it should*

Comment: At the moment the best option looks like taking each of the <path>s into libreoffice, recalculating the coordinates and putting them back!

Comment: Are you sure, that your line actually is the stroke of a path and not the inside of a line-shaped polygon (i.e., what you get if you apply *Stroke to Path* to a normal path)? Alternatively, the paths in question look scaled in one direction – maybe this helps to find the source of the issue.

Comment: Also, could you reduce your problem file to a minimal example and post it?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I'll try - not sure if I have a copy of the file with me today.  I suppose there's a chance matplotlib did something daft, but I'm pretty certain that it didn't - there's no fill colour only stroke, and the "filled" region is wider than twice the stroke width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did what I said in my comment, but I still think there must be a real solution.  I only had 4 paths in one file to deal with (I have seen this before actually, but the aspect ratio of the scale wasn't as bad and I didn't have time to worry about it).

This is what I did:

- Note the object IDs of the paths I wanted to edit
- open the .svg in jEdit
- Find each path in turn
- work on the `d` attribute
- replace " " with "\n"
- copy into libreoffice calc
- multiply the 2nd column, except the first 2 rows (only the 2nd of which was numeric) and the last row by 20 (my scaling factor)
- back to jEdit
- replace "\t" with "," (except after the "m", when it was just deleted
- replace "\n" with " "
- paste over the original path